# Blacklist connections in WSGIserver

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle

I’m running a simple WSGIsever with following code

```
botapp = bottle.app()
server = WSGIServer((myAddress, int(myPort)), botapp)
```

It’s logging more and more failed login attempts.

Searched for blacklist in WSGI documentation (https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html)

How to better implement dynamic update of blacklist, e.g. when new recurring failed attempt is detected, IP is added to blacklist and applied to new connections.

Much appreciate your input.

Comment: Are you confusing WSGI (the Python standard) and uWSGI (the software project)?

Comment: ron rothman, python standard, not SW project

Comment: Yes. You linked to uWSGI, which is not the SW project. It's not relevant to you (unless you're using uWSGI).